# Cloud Firestore creating a map when I want it to create an array in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store an array with an email as its key on a particular document within a collection in Cloud Firestore. At some instances when I write to the database and store the email along with its associated array it works fine but in another instance, the first part of the email up to the . is stored as the key along with a value of "com" and the associated array with com, thus making it a map. Does anyone have an idea on why this is happening and how to solve it.

I have tried going through the docs, but can't seem to find an answer on why it is happening.

```
//The code that works
self.db.collection("Access Codes").document(accessCode).setData([
    "access code": self.accessCode.text!,
    self.email.text!: ["****", self.fullNameField.text!]
])


//code that does not work
self.db.collection("Access Codes").document(accessCode).updateData([
    self.email.text!: ["****", self.fullNameField.text!]
])
```

This should become,
someone@gmail.com : ["****", "someone"]

But becomes 
someone@gmail: {com: [****, "someone"]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
self.db.collection("Access Codes").document(accessCode).updateData([
    self.email.text!: ["****", self.fullNameField.text!]
])
```

to this

```
self.db.collection("Access Codes").document(accessCode).updateData([
    [self.email.text!]: ["****", self.fullNameField.text!]
])
```

and see if it helps

Edit:
or this

```
self.db.collection("Access Codes").document(accessCode).setData([
    self.email.text!: ["****", self.fullNameField.text!]
], merge: true)
```

Comment: That causes my program to crash resulting in a sigabrt error

Comment: Ok, I am not a swift specialist but, from my understanding, the problem is that firebase sees someone@gmail =>.<= com this period as a dot notation and not as a part of an email. Test it by replacing the dot  with say $. Now if I am right, there is no way around it but to remove the dot. Field name can't contain ' . ' but field value can.

Comment: yes after some testing that proves to be true, I wonder if there is a work around

Comment: try replace .updateData with .setData with extra argument  `merge: true`